¿Cómo obtener la clave de servidor de Cloud Messaging para poder enviar notificaciones push entre dispositivos moviles? Android-Flutter
Estoy intentando de que un dispositivo movil envie una notificacion push a otro siguiendo un tutorial. En imagen se puede ver que en el tutorial que estoy siguiendo aparece la clave de servidor de cloud messaging

Pero cuando me situo en mi proyecto y busco la clave de servidor no aparece como se ve en la segunda imagen
El codigo principal que he realizado es el siguiente (imagen 3)

En la linea con rojo iria la clave de servidor que deseo obtener.
Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo obtengo dicha clave?
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, desde ya gracias.

Actualmente ya está en desuso esta api, pulsa en más informacion que la misma consola de firebase te da para que puedas guiarte en la implementación
